# Why did my Oscar change color?

Tags: health, fish, biology, cichlid

Both pictures are the same Oscar. I was hoping someone can tell me if it normal for him to change colors like that.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take a minute to take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. Please note that species / breed identification is considered off-topic here, as per [this Meta discussion](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/12501). The only part of your question that is on topic is if the color change is normal. Please [edit] your question to remove the part about breed identification.

Comment: did you do major changes to its habitat recently ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, oscar fish do not change color unless the water is bad, ammonia or nitrite are present and/or a large change in pH in your water (you need to take a water test to be sure about this).

Some types of carp and plecos can change color if there is a change in the pH of the water. If plecos are stressed they looks almost grey.

Carp fish can change color in a radical way if the pH changes. Goldfish and koi can lose all of their color when the pH changes (after buying koi I have seen orange koi getting totally white in less than 24 hours), but the color will return to normal when the fish have adjusted to the new water.

Many types of fish can change color if they experience stress, changing temperature-pH-ammonia-nitrite or simply by getting disturbed when you clean their tank.

Comment: The color change because of different PH, will it last, or is it only stress-caused and would get away after time?

Comment: if it is only the PH that is off your fish will change back to the normal color,please take a water test and post the results i need to know the ph-ammonia-nitrite-nitrate to tell you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Oscar’s tend to change colour both depending on the water levels but also on their moods. If an Oscar is angry or upset they’ll tend to be a whiter colour, whereas if they are happy and content they’ll go a dark colour. My Oscar does it when he is hungry.